# MPLS auto-bandwidth balancing

Tags: juniper, mpls, rsvp

I operate an MPLS/IP network that utilizes auto-bandwidth to measure bandwidth utilization and signal RSVP accordingly.
How can I maintain balance across my LSP paths such that one large [P router]-to-[P router] path/flow doesn't saturate any one link?

I think that by creating more equal-cost LSPs, traffic should be getting balanced at the cost of increased signaling overhead.
I'm also considering lowering the statistics measurement interval for closer-to-reality signaling bandwidths, but at the cost of increased measurement time and signaling overhead.

What's the best way to find the optimal balance of full-mesh LSP count and statistics interval?

The routing platform here is Juniper JunOS.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly want to ECMP LSP's, how many to use depends on traffic levels relative to link bandwidths (critically you want to avoid LSP's being unsignalable due to being larger then a choke point).

For auto-bandwidth intervals it depends on what your aiming for, a few times an hour isn't a bad number, but less frequent may be better if you have fewer flows.